# Hierarchical process of exponentials

Tags: conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution, hierarchical-bayesian

I'd like to work with a what I believe is a called a "hierarchical process" -- given by the multiplication of a pair of exponential distributions such that the random variable from one process is the parameter of the second process:

$$p(x,y|a,c) = p(x|a)p(y|c,x)$$

where $a, c$ are parameters and $p(x|a) = ae^{-ax}$ is an exponential distribution, and $y$ is an exponential distribution with parameter $\frac{c}{x}$, so that $p(y|c, x) = (\frac{c}{x})e^{\frac{-c*y}{x}}$.

The difficulty, here, is that I can't figure out how to integrate over all $x\in [0,\infty]$ and find the marginal distribution for $y$. Indeed, it kind of surprises me that this function results in such a complication. Note: if I expand the exp function in $p(y|c,x)$ in an infinite series, and then try to integrate, I get Gamma functions that have singularities.

Q: Has this anyone seen this sort of formulation? And, furthermore, is it not a "red flag" that the integration to obtain the marginal of $y$ does not seem "well-behaved"?

Answer (score 0):

My integral has a solution, after all. As per Lucian at the Mathematics StackExchange:

$~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp\bigg(-ax-\frac bx\bigg)~\frac{dx}x~=~2K_0\Big(2\sqrt{ab}\Big),~$